# How to execute code for each recipe in a Bitbake function?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Basically I want to do this in a my recipe's function:

```
for each recipe
    print recipe.DESCRIPTION
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bbclass in some layer (`meta-yourlayer/classes/`) and then add it to `INHERIT` in a configuration file (machine, distro, layer.conf, local.conf).

The following content might be of inspiration, not tested:

```
python __anonymous() {
    bb.warn(d.getVar('DESCRIPTION'))
}
```

though the documentation states that anonymous functions might not work, c.f.
<s>https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-INHERIT.</s>

If that's the case, you should probably add a task right after `do_fetch` (and that might even fix the "issue" explained right after this).

Note that this makes the class inherited globally and the anonymous function is executed at parsing time. I'm not sure this actually makes any sense for you since all recipes, even those not used, will print that message.

See <s>https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#inherit-configuration-directive.</s>